# Hotmail not receiving e-mails

Tags: smtp, email

I have a server that can't send e-mails to some Hotmail accounts. How could I fix this?

For Gmail accounts, it sends well.

I saw the headers of an e-mail sent to a Gmail account and can confirm that SPF and DKIM are correctly set.

I also checked [here](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) if the IP is blacklisted and it wasn't.

What else could it be?

**EDIT**

I just want a LIST of all the things that I should try to find why my e-mails are not received by Hotmail accounts.

I tried everything I saw on the Web but without success. Maybe I'm missing something and this is what I want to know with this LIST that I'm asking for.

My clients are starting to complain about this issue...

By the way, I'm new in this type of e-mail problems.

Comment: Any number of things, including the e-mail's actual contents. Hotmail is notoriously strict and overzealous WRT spam prevention.

Comment: But the e-mail's are well received by Gmail. Is it too difficult to make them get to Hotmail account's?

Comment: Gmail and Hotmail are run by different companies with different rules and spam filters. It working on one means nothing about the other.

Comment: So do I need to contact them in order to know what is happening?

Comment: They have a variety of tools. Try https://postmaster.live.com/snds/

Comment: Check if reverse DNS is working for your email server. While you may not be blacklisted, if reverse DNS is not working then many services will still block you.

Comment: Yes, Reverse DNS is working well =S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. Spf ok, no smtp blacklist (checking MX Toolbox http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx was clear)

What it turned out to be was a hacked site on the same server blacklisted the IP and any mention of the site url in emails sent (normally the users signature).

So in summary, it seems in addition to SPAM blacklists, there are additional malware blacklists which contain filter and domain words in the event a site has been compromised and had phising scripts uploaded.

When I had my issue, mxtoolbox was clear, but sideadvisor was not.

I had to clean the Joomla infection, patch, remove driveby files and submit a report to http://www.siteadvisor.com/ to get the site delisted.

Comment: But I already saw if this IP was blacklisted and it isn't. I Edited my question because I forgot to include the link where I verified for blacklists

Comment: No, as per my post I had the *exact* same issue. MX Toolbox was clear. Siteadvisor.com and mywot.com showed it as an unsafe site. I would recommend checking those safe sites also for your domain.

Comment: I tried that but they said that my IP was not tested yet or that it doesn't have reviews yet. Is it a good signal?